# Can a Java Session expire if there is an object reference to it?

Tags: java, session, servlets

Suppose I have a Java web application and I set my session time-out to 10 minutes. I also have a `Collection<HttpSession>` in my servlet context which stores all currently existing sessions (ignore the non/usefulness of this collection). With this setup, can a Session object actually expire? The collection will live throughout the entire application's lifetime, holding a reference to each session.

1. If a session DOES expire, then what happens if I try to access the session at a later time? Do I get a(n) (nullpointer)Exception? Or could the session already be recycled and thus I'm not accessing the session I think I was?
2. If a session CAN NO LONGER EXPIRE, what can I do to remedy this?
3. Does this behaviour differ for each different servlet containerv(tomcat, jboss, jetty...) or is it more or less consistent?

Comment: Can a session expire? Yes. When the page hasn't been accessed for 10 minutes. The server must always have references to valid session instances, so at a minimum, there are two references to every session instance in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you, as a web developer, are maintaining the sessions in a collection when web container does something similar (and more). Since you usually request the session from the container via the `HttpServletRequest` object, even if you maintained another reference to it (so as to perhaps prevent it from garbage collection), the web container has no knowledge of it, so the session will expire (in the most straightforward sense of the word).

> If a session DOES expire, then what happens if I try to access the session at a later time?

A web container, like Tomcat, maintains a session for requests. Considering that cookies are managing the sessions, every request will send the same cookies to the same server, so the web container arranges for finding the session and returning it to you from the request object. See [getSession() API](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession()). Here, based on the value of the argument, you can request new or existing session from the web container.

> Do I get a(n) (null pointer) Exception?

Maybe. See the API above (the boolean argument, `getSession` is overloaded).

> Or could the session already be recycled and thus I'm not accessing the session I think I was?

Yes, that is entirely possible. If the session expires (e.g. after some inactivity), since you asked the web container to expire it, you have lost it (so to speak).

> If a session CAN NO LONGER EXPIRE, what can I do to remedy this?

That is rather strange, however it may be possible based on web container implementation. All web containers (should) provide a configuration that helps configure the default session timeout (and I think servlet spec provides the default value). It is rather unsafe to have no expiry on session timeouts. Check the documentation of your web container to see how to configure this. There should be a way to limit the session's validity.

> Does this behaviour differ for each different servlet container env(tomcat, jboss, jetty...) or is it more or less consistent?

The idea of sessions and session timeouts are the same across containers since it relates to HTTP and it is part of the servlet spec. Every container has its documentation to configure its default session timeout.

Comment: Made it clear, thanks. As to why... well it's actually a Map<Username, Collection<HttpSession>>. This way my application can always know which sessions are linked to each user. When logging in, there is a maximum allowed amount of sessions any username can have (typically this is set to 1). Additionally, a username can do certain things that have consequences in ALL of his sessions (in case amount > 1), and I need easy access to that username's other sessions. The colection of sessions is easily maintained by using listeners and sessionbinding interfaces.

Comment: Cool. Whereas your use of session is creative, it may not scale. What if tomorrow you want to track the login and logout times in each session? Such transient properties are maintained in the databases these days (for analytics, e.g.). Maintaining large sessions objects especially when they are expired and for something like this is perhaps not called for.

Comment: Well actually I DO want the sessions to expire, and when they expire, the user object inside them gets unbound, which in turn will it remove the session from the Map in my servlet context programmatically by using a httpsessionbindinglistener. That was the whole point of this question, I was afraid the old obsolete sessions might get stuck in my map forever (or worse, get recycled for another username)! But since that's not the case, everything should go smoothly.
I already have a user table in the Db that tracks last and penultimatelogin datetime, but that seems unrelated to this question.